# Why is the following function $\int_E\frac{y}{x} e^{-x}\sin x\;d\mu$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Why is the following function inside the integral $\int_E\frac{y}{x} e^{-x}\sin x\; d\mu$ measurable where $\mu$ is the product measure on $R$ with itself and $ E = \{ (x,y) : 0 \leq y \leq \sqrt{x}\}$?

Comment: Because it is continuous except on the ordinate axis?

Comment: Why writing an integral if all that matters is the function inside it?